# Break up a string using AWK or PERL

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I know you can use field delimiters to break up a field in AWK, however I have a question regarding a string without any delimiters. I need to process to following data, and I'm not sure how to start:

```
RyanWehe989987412rwehe@asu.edu2025550126CO2001BlakeStDenver80205
JosephLee605497184josephl@mailinator.com3035550103CO5986BudweiserWayAlamosa81101
AmyJohnson783333251amyj@mailinator.com6515550164MN14N5thStMinneapolis55403
DanielJEverhard314849866everhard@asu.edu5059358554NM8830JohnsonRdAlbuquerque87122
PhilipEPeterson325764011peterson@asu.edu4561238888WA542468thAveLacey98513
MattVNulk124085733nulk@asu.edu2093865442KSManhattanStRiley87512
BrandonTLyons123456123btlyons1@asu.edu5755595459AZ635WElmStMesa85212
RogerATurtle983421567rat@gmail.com8587754321IA3400SWIslanDrdDesmoines50021
MarcJWhiz745629754marcwhiz76@yahoo.com6195323200CA215NCollegeGroveWaySandiego91210
```

I want to format the raw data into this:

```
Ryan Wehe, 989-98-7412
2001 Blake St 
Denver, CO 80205
wehe@asu.edu    
(202) 555-0126  

Joseph Lee, 605-49-7184
5986 Budweiser Way 
Alamosa, CO 81101
josephl@mailinator.com
(303) 555-0103

AmyJohnson, 783-33-3251
14 N 5th St 
Minneapolis, MN 55403
amyj@mailinator.com
(651) 555-0164
```

Comment: Do you *have* to use Awk or is any language acceptable?

Comment: I can use a combo of AWK and PERL

Comment: Did that work for you? You never accepted the answer.

Comment: This is not parsable `542468thAve` which is the building number which is the street name?

Comment: Yes I think it's an error in the assignment, I'm not sure what to do there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, Awk provides no facilitity for using capture groups to define the field separator.

In consideration of this I think a quick hack might be your best option:

```
cat addresses.txt | perl -ne '/([A-Z][[:lower:]]*)([A-Z]*[[:lower:]]*)([0-9]{9})(.*?\.\w{2,3})([0-9]{10})(.*?)([0-9]{5})/ && print "$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6\n"'
```

Which returns this:

```
Ryan Wehe 989987412 rwehe@asu.edu 2025550126 CO2001BlakeStDenver 80205
Joseph Lee 605497184 josephl@mailinator.com 3035550103 CO5986BudweiserWayAlamosa 81101
Amy Johnson 783333251 amyj@mailinator.com 6515550164 MN14N5thStMinneapolis 55403
Daniel JEverhard 314849866 everhard@asu.edu 5059358554 NM8830JohnsonRdAlbuquerque 87122
Philip EPeterson 325764011 peterson@asu.edu 4561238888 WA 54246
Matt VNulk 124085733 nulk@asu.edu 2093865442 KSManhattanStRiley 87512
Brandon TLyons 123456123 btlyons1@asu.edu 5755595459 AZ635WElmStMesa 85212
Roger ATurtle 983421567 rat@gmail.com 8587754321 IA3400SWIslanDrdDesmoines 50021
Marc JWhiz 745629754 marcwhiz76@yahoo.com 6195323200 CA215NCollegeGroveWaySandiego 91210
```

Your answer uses both formats so I was unsure if you you need to break names apart (i.e Ryan Wehe instead of RyanWehe), adjusting it to this is fairly straitforward.

Comment: Thanks, this is the best I've seen and I'll use this. Thank you very much!